# Code Sign error after changing Product Name of iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, build

I have to change the name of my app.  I've done the following (Xcode 4):

Targets > Packaging > Product Name

And changed the name (for dev/ad hoc/release).  When building I get the following error

```
Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Distribution' doesn't match any identity in any profile
```

If I change the name back, it works fine.  I can't submit to the store with the original name (the one that works).  Do I need to create a new app ID in the provisioning portal?  I'd hate to do that because I have push notifications already tied to the existing app ID.

I've tried 'clean' and then building again - doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  The provisioning profile is tied to a specific bundle id.

i.e. "com.mycompany.myproduct"

If you change this, it will definitely break code-signing.

Alternatively, [change the app name](http://happy-coding.com/change-product_name-in-iphone-project/), but [leave the bundle identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309821/xcode-bundle-identifier-formatting-from-product-name) the same:

Targets > Info >

bundle display name = "my new product name" (remove the ${PRODUCT_NAME})
bundle identifier = "com.mycompany.myproduct" (remove the ${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier})

Comment: that sounds like exactly what I want to do.  The first link you provided sounded like the Xcode 3 version of what I described as doing in Xcode 4.  I've looked at it closer and found that the change I made updated the bundle identifier as well.  I edited the 'Bundle display name' itself in the Info tab and that did the trick. Much obliged.