# Change bundle identifier in Xcode when submitting my first app in IOS

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to submit my first app in `iOS`. I have entered `iOS Provisioning Portal` and I am about to create an app ID.

Lets say that I name my bundle identifier:

```
com.mycompany.appdemo
```

Then going to Xcode and in the summary section I want to change the bundle identifier.

But I cannot erase what is being written there, only the start of it. The name of my app is in grey color and I cannot delete it or change it.

So I see in grey color somethng like this `App-Demo` which is the name of the project in the left side.

My question is this:
Is it a problem? Do I have to create a new app id named `com.mycompany.App-Demo` or something else?

Here is a picture also.
[image]
As you can see I can only edit the first part.

Comment: The question and answer are outdated

Comment: Probably yes since originally was asked >5 years ago.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

By default, Xcode sets the bundle identifier to the bundle/company identifier that you set during project creation + project name.

[image: Project Creation - Bundle/Company Identifier + Product Name]

This is similar to what you see in the Project > Summary screen.

[image: Project > Summary]

But you can change this in the Project > Info screen. (This is the Info.plist.)

[image: Project > Info]

Comment: important note, you might have to clean & rebuild after changing the identifier

Comment: Note as well that when I did this, apparently the path to my core data file changed (must be a function of the bundle name?).  So, the next run of the app found itself without a core data file.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I would never have guessed that it's possible to change the Bundle identifier directly in the Info.plist.

Comment: @neilvillareal it Appears to change it, but actually it does not change it. I have noticed it after I set up a Distribution Provisioning Profile in developer.apple.com and then when I tried ti import it, it said that "Provisioning profile "Mrev" has app ID "com.vividapartmentsteam.Mrev", which does not match the bundle ID "com.vividapartments.Mrev"." I must say that I am using Cocoa pods and if you right click Mrev.Xcworspace, Show Package Contents, right click project.xcworkspace, open with Sublime, you will see no changes under PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER or Organization.

Comment: I mean, if I open Mrev.xcodeproj, I made a typo above and said xcworkspace instead of .xcodeproj

Comment: This is outdated yet there is no specification of xcode version

Comment: Such a simple answer, but I couldn't find it anywhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

I know that its late but it might be helpful for people who need to change the Bundle Identifier of the app. In the finder go to the project folder:

```
the project file --> Right click on your project file '*.xcodeproj'
```

[image]

```
--> choose 'Show Package Contents' 
--> Double click to open 'project.pbxproj' file
```

[image]

```
--> find 'productName = NAME_YOU_WANT_TO_CHANGE' in the 
    '/* Begin PBXNativeTarget section */'
```

The ${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier} variable will be replaced with the name you have entered and new Bundle Identifier will be updated to what you need it to be.

Answer (score 13):

Here's the answer from Apple's official documentation, just tried, it's working.

**Setting the Bundle ID**

The default bundle ID in your Xcode project is a string formatted as a reverse-domain—for example, *com.MyCompany.MyProductName*. To create the default bundle ID, Xcode concatenates the company identifier with the product name you entered when creating the project from a template, as described in [Setting Properties When Creating Your Xcode Project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH28-SW11). (Xcode replaces spaces in the product name to create the default bundle ID.) It may be sufficient to replace the company identifier prefix in the bundle ID or you can replace the entire bundle ID. For example, change the company identifier prefix to match your company domain name or replace the entire bundle ID to match an explicit App ID.

For Mac apps, ensure that every bundle ID is unique within your app bundle. For example, if your app bundle includes a helper app, ensure that its bundle ID is different from your app’s bundle ID.

Follow these steps to change the bundle ID prefix in the General pane in the project editor.

**To set the bundle ID prefix**

1. In the project navigator, select the project and your target to
   display the project editor.
2. Click General and, if necessary, click the disclosure triangle next
   to Identity to reveal the settings.

[image]

3. Enter the bundle ID prefix in the “Bundle Identifier” field.

**To set the bundle ID**

1. In the project navigator, select the project and your target to
   display the project editor.
2. Click Info.
3. Enter the bundle ID in the Value column of the “Bundle identifier”
   row.

[image]

If you're feeling interested in reading more, please check [APP Distribution Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH28-SW1) from Apple.

Comment: OP was asking how to change the project name. Above steps are for setting up a project.

Answer (score 11):

Just change **Product Name** in your project's build settings. This will change the bundle identifier with no need to manually touch xcode configuration files.

Answer (score 9):

Just edit the Project name by single click on the Top of project navigator window, will work in this case. You need not to try any other thing. :)

Comment: I just have to add that I had to delete and re-add the Build Scheme for it to reflect the new name after this.

Answer (score 7):

This solve my problem.

Just change the **Bundle identifier** from Build Setting.

```
 Navigate to Project >> Build Setting >> Product Bundle Identifier
```

Answer (score 6):

Actually you can change it in **Build Settings**; at the bottom there is a section "**User-Defined**" where you can easily change **PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER.**

I prefer this way, because if you change the info variable you are altering the reference to the other value.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

A very simple solution to that is to open the file:

```
YOURPROJECT.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
```

And find for this variable:

```
PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER
```

You'll see something like that:

```
PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = com.YOUR_APP_NAME.SOMETHING;
```

So, the name on the right is your Bundle Identifier. In my case it works perfectly.

Comment: If it is Flutter project, sometimes the value might be in many places in the same file, make sure to change the value in all the matching places

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 7

Select root node of your project -> In editor click on project name -> Select targets -> Identity -> Bundle Identifier

Answer (score 1):

[View this picture to see how you can change the bundle identifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iovIJ.jpg)

**Explanation:**

1. Select your project form the leftmost project navigator
2. Under the General Tab, there is a section called Targets inside where you will see the name of your project. Click on the name.
3. Then you will be able to see the bundle identifier which you can change as below:

As you can see in the picture, the name of my App is PracticeApp.
And my bundle identifier is:
**com.hello500.PracticeApp**

In this case,
You can change **hello500** to change the bundle identifier of the app.

Answer (score 0):

In XCode 7 you can update your bundle identifier by double clicking your target and changing the name.  [image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing a cordova app, make sure to change the version and bundle identifier in the `config.xml` as well