# Mac application bundle ID not changing

Tags: macos, cocoa, game-center, gamekit

I am trying to change my Mac's app ID, but it's simply not being updated!

I changed the plist, however, when I run the game center code, I get his:

> NSUnderlyingError=0x1013a1a50 "The operation couldn’t be completed. status = 5019, Game descriptor does not specify a valid game: { bundle-version = "1"; 
>   bundle-id = "com.company.OldID"; }"}

I have changed the `OldID` to `newID`, but it's not reflecting in Game center, why?!

Answer (score 3):

This can happen because you aren't running your game in the Sandbox environment. Try this:

1. Check into iTunesConnect > Manage Your Applications > App Information:

   Verify the Bundle ID matches the one specified in the Info.plist file.
2. Confirm that your game is running in the **Sandbox**, and not on the real server.

   The error showing coincides with your game trying to use a real live server (where it's not registered), and should be running in the Sandbox for testing. This can also happen when you start the app in the simulator and you're already logged into Game Center. Log out from Game Center before you start testing your app, then when prompted log in.

From Apple Developer Portal:

> As a developer, your Game Center account may be logged into either
>   Sandbox for testing, or into the live environment but not both. To
>   change which account you are logged into, switch to the built-in Game
>   Center app and log out, then run any Game Center enabled app. If that
>   app is provisioned for development, enter your test account
>   information to log into Sandbox. Otherwise, enter your live account
>   information to log into the live environment.

Tips for this answer are thanks to [holadev](http://holadev.wordpress.com) .

Comment: Thanks, I am in sandbox mode, and I even [tied to force it.](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/168811?tstart=0). Regarding the Bundle ID note, that's what my question is, right? I am trying to change the bundle ID to match itunes connect, without success.

Comment: Have you tried this? > http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/45546, or possibly this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12546648/499581 - I would would think it might be related.

Comment: Yup, that's the forced sandbox mode right there... I'm sure I tried that... I really think the project file is corrupt.