# Can i change bundle identifier later

Tags: ios

we all know this window which asks about various details including company identifier/bundle identifier.

[image]

My question is, say at the time I create the project, I write some company/bundle identifier because I don't have developer account at that point in time or smth else.

Later, when I decided to submit the app to appstore, can I change this bundle identifier to something more proper?

Comment: Just search **change bundle identifier name** on google.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can change.
Go to settings of project. Change there.

This will help you

[Change bundle identifier in Xcode when submitting my first app in IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12545174/change-bundle-identifier-in-xcode-when-submitting-my-first-app-in-ios)

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** , you can do that.

when submitting to appstore you can change the bundle identifier.[image]

Select New Bundle identifier for submit the app to appstore.